# Python - using more than one word in !=

Tags: python

I want to use more than one word in !=, but I can't for the life of me understand or google my way how to. 
Can anyone help, and explain why I can't just do it like:
!= "No" != "no" !="n" !="N":             etc etc

```
answers = ["Yes", "Not now not ever.", "Unclear answer, try again.", "Maybe.", "Probably not.", "Try again later.",
           "My sources says no.", "My sources says yes.", "Only when there is a full moon.", "It is certain.",
           "Cannot predict now.", "Outlook not so good", "Very doubtful.", "You may rely on it.",
           "Yes - definitely.", "As I see it, yes.", "Signs point to yes."]    

while str(input("Do you want to ask the Magic 8Ball a question?  Yes or No?  ")) != "No" != "no": # <-- problematic line
    str(input("Ask the mighty 8Ball your question:  "))
    randomanswer = answers[random.randint(0, len(answers) -1)]
    print("\n","The Magic 8Ball says: ")
    print(randomanswer, "\n")    
else:
    return
```

Comment: The language just isn't designed this way. Assign the input to a variable and compare this variable then to one after another.

Comment: Maybe you could use `not in` instead? e.g. `while answer not in ['no', 'No']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a tuple of sentinel-values, e.g.

```
while foo not in ('No', 'no', 'N', 'n'):
    # code
```

or

```
while foo.lower() not in ('no', 'n'):
    # code
```

If there are a huge amount of sentinels, a `set` will perform faster than a tuple (for low amounts of values, hashing is not worth it).

You might also want to look into the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module for more sophisticated pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while str(input("Do you want to ask the Magic 8Ball a question?  Yes or No?  ")) not in ["No", "no"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a way to chain together *conditional statements*. Unfortunately you cannot do it the way you're trying to do. However, you can use `and` and `or` to chain them together, which is how it's normally done. For example:

```
userinput = str(input("Do you want to ask the Magic 8Ball a question?  Yes or No?  "))

while userinput != "No" and userinput != "no":
    # have to get user input again at end of loop
```

But an even better approach is to find how to logically turn this into a single conditional, in this case using `lower` on the user input:

```
userinput = str(input("Do you want to ask the Magic 8Ball a question?  Yes or No?  "))
userinput = userinput.lower() # make it lowercase

while userinput != "no":
    # have to get user input again at end of loop
```

Finally, you can use `random.choice` to provide a random element from your answers array.

Answer (score 0):

Change your problematic line to:

```
while input("Do you want to ask the Magic 8Ball a question?  Yes or No?  ").strip().lower() != "no":
```

This way, you convert the input string to lowercase (`lower()`) while also stripping any space the user might have typed in (`strip()`)

Then, if user types: "No", `lower()` will convert it to all lowercase, "no" and then check it towards your `!= 'no'`.

Anything typed into `input()` is a string, so can omit the `str()`.